# How to display a confirm box before submitting a form using jquery confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form and I want to show a confirmation massage after clicking submit button and also I don't want to use following method

```
return confirm("Are You Sure?")
```

I used [JQuery Confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) as following.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("SubmitTest", "HydrostaticReception", FormMethod.Post, new {id="ReceptionForm", onsubmit = "ValidateMyform(this);" }))
    {
    .....
    <button onclick="SubmitMyForm()">Submit</button>
    }
```

The javascript codes are ...

```
function ValidateMyform(form) {
        // get all the inputs within the submitted form
        var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            // only validate the inputs that have the required attribute
            if (inputs[i].hasAttribute("required")) {
                if (inputs[i].value == "") {
                    // found an empty field that is required
                    alert("Fill all fields");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

The Javascript code for showing Confirm Box (According [JQuery Confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)) is

```
function SubmitMyForm() {
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Confirm!',
            content: 'Are you sure?',
            buttons: {
                No: function () {
                    return true;
                },
                Yes: function () {
                    $("#ReceptionForm").submit();
                    //alert("For Test");
                    //document.getElementById("ReceptionForm").submit();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

**The Problem IS...**

When I click Submit button it doesn't wait for me to click Yes button in Confirm box and the form will submit (the Confirm box appears and after 1 sec disappear and form submits).

But when I use **alert("For Test");** instead of **$("#ReceptionForm").submit();** , it works correctly. Does anybody knows why I'm facing this problem?!!!

Comment: By default your button is a submit button (so you need `<button type="button">` But you should be handling the the forms `.submit()` event and cancelling it if you click the 'No' button. And that is not the way to validate - use validation attributes on your properties and enable client side validation (using `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js)`

Comment: You do not prevent the default (form submit) in your function, so it submits. this might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/3350247/125981

Comment: Stephen & Mark, Thanks to both of you because of your useful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a "flag" to know if the confirmation occured or not to ["prevent default"](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) submit behavior.

Remove the inline `onsubmit = "ValidateMyform(this);"` and use a jQuery event handler instead.

```
var confirmed = false;
$("#ReceptionForm").on("submit", function(e){

  // if confirm == true here
  // And if the form is valid...

  // the event won't be prevented and the confirm won't show.
  if(!confirmed && ValidateMyform($(this)[0]) ){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.confirm({
      title: 'Confirm!',
      content: 'Are you sure?',
      buttons: {
        No: function () {
          return;
        },
        Yes: function () {
          confirmed = true;
          $("#ReceptionForm").submit();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: should `return true;` really be `return false;`?

Comment: Whatever.. This return has no effect. Just return.